# Need the Groovy way to do partial file substitutions

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a file that I need to modify.  The part I need to modify (not the entire file), is similar to the properties shown below.  The problem is that I only need to replace part of the "value", the "ConfigurablePart" if you will.  I receive this file so can not control it's format.

```
alpha.beta.gamma.1 = constantPart1ConfigurablePart1
alpha.beta.gamma.2 = constantPart2ConfigurablePart2
alpha.beta.gamma.3 = constantPart3ConfigurablePart3
```

I made this work this way, though I know it is really bad!

```
def updateFile(String pattern, String updatedValue) {
    def myFile = new File(".", "inputs/fileInherited.txt")
    StringBuffer updatedFileText = new StringBuffer()
    def ls = System.getProperty('line.separator')
    myFile.eachLine{ line ->
        def regex = Pattern.compile(/$pattern/)
        def m = (line =~ regex)
        if (m.matches()) {
            def buf = new StringBuffer(line)
            buf.replace(m.start(1), m.end(1), updatedValue)
            line = buf.toString()
        }
        println line
        updatedFileText.append(line).append(ls)
    }
    myFile.write(updatedFileText.toString())
}
```

The passed in pattern is required to contain a group that is substituted in the StringBuffer.  Does anyone know how this should really be done in Groovy?

**EDIT -- to define the expected output**

The file that contains the example lines needs to be updated such that the "ConfigurablePart" of each line is replaced with the updated text provided.  For my ugly solution, I would need to call the method 3 times, once to replace ConfigurablePart1, once for ConfigurablePart2, and finally for ConfigurablePart3.  There is likely a better approach to this too!!!

****UPDATED -- Answer that did what I really needed ****

In case others ever hit a similar issue, the groovy code improvements I asked about are best reflected in the accepted answer.  However, for my problem that did not quite solve my issues.  As I needed to substitute only a portion of the matched lines, I needed to use back-references and groups.  The only way I could make this work was to define a three-part regEx like:

```
(.*)(matchThisPart)(.*)
```

Once that was done, I was able to use:

```
it.replaceAdd(~/$pattern/, "\$1$replacement\$3")
```

Thanks to both replies - each helped me out a lot!

Comment: Expected output please ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be made more verbose with the use of closure as args. Here is how this can be done:

```
//abc.txt
abc.item.1 = someDummyItem1
abc.item.2 = someDummyItem2
abc.item.3 = someDummyItem3
alpha.beta.gamma.1 = constantPart1ConfigurablePart1
alpha.beta.gamma.2 = constantPart2ConfigurablePart2
alpha.beta.gamma.3 = constantPart3ConfigurablePart3
abc.item.4 = someDummyItem4
abc.item.5 = someDummyItem5
abc.item.6 = someDummyItem6
```

Groovy Code:-

```
//Replace the pattern in file and write to file sequentially.
def replacePatternInFile(file, Closure replaceText) {
    file.write(replaceText(file.text))
}

def file = new File('abc.txt')
def patternToFind = ~/ConfigurablePart/
def patternToReplace = 'NewItem'

//Call the method
replacePatternInFile(file){
    it.replaceAll(patternToFind, patternToReplace)
}

println file.getText()

//Prints:
abc.item.1 = someDummyItem1
abc.item.2 = someDummyItem2
abc.item.3 = someDummyItem3
alpha.beta.gamma.1 = constantPart1NewItem1
alpha.beta.gamma.2 = constantPart2NewItem2
alpha.beta.gamma.3 = constantPart3NewItem3
abc.item.4 = someDummyItem4
abc.item.5 = someDummyItem5
abc.item.6 = someDummyItem6
```

Confirm file `abc.txt`. I have not used the method `updateFile()` as done by you, but you can very well parameterize as below:-

```
def updateFile(file, patternToFind, patternToReplace){
   replacePatternInFile(file){
      it.replaceAll(patternToFind, patternToReplace)
   }
}
```

Comment: Sequentially, not simultaneously ;-)

Comment: @tim_yates Good catch. Updated instantaneously. :P

Comment: Since I had multiple patterns, I used the Map approach from the first response as a great way to supply the Patterns and Replacements to the technique above.

Answer (score 3):

For a quick answer I'd just go this route:

```
patterns =  [pattern1 : constantPart1ConfigurablePart1,
     pattern2 : constantPart2ConfigurablePart2,
     pattern3 : constantPart3ConfigurablePart3]


def myFile = new File(".", "inputs/fileInherited.txt")
StringBuffer updatedFileText = new StringBuffer()
def ls = System.getProperty('line.separator')
myFile.eachLine{ line ->
    patterns.each { pattern, replacement ->
        line = line.replaceAll(pattern, replacement)
    }
    println line
    updatedFileText.append(line).append(ls)
}
myFile.write(updatedFileText.toString())
```

Comment: If you need to do it in place look at- http://blog.davidehringer.com/groovy/processing-files-place-groovy/

Comment: I wish I could check both answers, I mainly used the solution below, but combined your approach with the pattern Map - very nice - thanks!