# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to replace text

Tags: java, groovy, replace, gradle

I'm trying to replace text in a .cfg file.

I'm using Gradle, so a mix of Java and Groovy really.

Here's my current code. This should grab the first line of the property, add `\n` to begin a new line, and then the contents of the file I'm importing the text (the text is underneath):

```
String filename = "settings/code_cfg.cfg"
File f = new File(filename)
String text = f.getText()
String replace = "$1 \n" + text
dspaceCfgTxt = dspaceCfgTxt.replaceFirst(/(filter.plugins.*)/, replace) <!-- This is line 545
```

**EDIT: The text consists of multiple multiline properties, like the one underneath:**

```
filter.plugins =  property.sub.random.jibberish \
                  property.second.random \
                  property.lala
```

The contents of the file `code_cfg.cfg` I'm importing the text from is the following:

```
a random property \
```

**EDIT: So the final result should be something like this:**

```
filter.plugins =  property.sub.random.jibberish \
                  a random property \
                  property.second.random \
                  property.lala
```

But I'm getting the following error when I try to execute:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 28
    at java_lang_String$replaceFirst.call(Unknown Source)
    at build_mv9ue0gaar4db2nj1lt6j3olk$_run_closure35.doCall(/Users/user/build.gradle:545)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:485)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:469)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskStatusNagger$1.execute(TaskStatusNagger.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskStatusNagger$1.execute(TaskStatusNagger.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:64)
    ... 57 more
```

And I have no idea why. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16927133/2051952) help?

Comment: @dmahapatro Certainly does help a bit to make the whole process easier, but the problem remains the same: the `replaceAll` statement...

Comment: @dmahapatro Ah, foolish me. The code on the link works perfectly, my regex just wasn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's really a Groovy question. One mistake that I can spot is that `"$1"` is Groovy String interpolation and will look for a variable named `1`. Instead it has to be `'$1'`.