# how to replace a string/word in a text file in groovy

Tags: groovy

Hello I am using groovy 2.1.5 and I have to write a code which show the contens/files of a directory with a given path then it makes a backup of the file and replace a word/string from the file.
here is the code I have used to try to replace a word in the file selected

```
String contents = new File( '/geretd/resume.txt' ).getText( 'UTF-8' ) 
contents = contents.replaceAll( 'visa', 'viva' )
```

also here is my complete code if anyone would like to modify it in a more efficient way, I will appreciate it since I am learning.

```
def dir = new File('/geretd')
dir.eachFile { 
    if (it.isFile()) {
        println it.canonicalPath
    }
}

copy = { File src,File dest-> 

    def input = src.newDataInputStream()
    def output = dest.newDataOutputStream()

    output << input 

    input.close()
    output.close()
}

//File srcFile  = new File(args[0])
//File destFile = new File(args[1])

File srcFile  = new File('/geretd/resume.txt')
File destFile = new File('/geretd/resumebak.txt')
copy(srcFile,destFile)

x = " "
println x

def dire = new File('/geretd')
dir.eachFile { 
    if (it.isFile()) {
        println it.canonicalPath
    }
}

String contents = new File( '/geretd/resume.txt' ).getText( 'UTF-8' ) 
contents = contents.replaceAll( 'visa', 'viva' )
```

Answer (score 40):

As an alternative to loading the whole file into memory, you could do each line in turn

```
new File( 'destination.txt' ).withWriter { w ->
  new File( 'source.txt' ).eachLine { line ->
    w << line.replaceAll( 'World', 'World!!!' ) + System.getProperty("line.separator")
  }
}
```

Of course this (and [dmahapatro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17396047/6509)) rely on the words you are replacing not spanning across lines

Comment: for me this gives : scripts are not permitet to use java.lang.File...

Answer (score 40):

As with nearly everything Groovy, AntBuilder is the easiest route:

```
ant.replace(file: "myFile", token: "NEEDLE", value: "replacement")
```

Comment: This was the answer that I was looking for. I knew that there was a one-line solution for this but I couldn't remember it. This worked perfectly for me. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the docs, I'd say no: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html

Comment: This seems to work but it will not allow me to replace the opening XML tag in a document with a different value. It will replace the closing tag though.

Comment: How would you use a wildcard in the **token**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky @paulo-pedroso You can use `ant.replaceregexp(file: 'myFile', match: 'my regexp', replace:'my replacement string')`

Comment: Hey, if Groovy has to load Ant all the time, why not just use Ant in the first place! Imagine all the people in here who are running Groovy in Maven and then it's loading Ant hullabaloo in the background. Talk about a steaming pile of dependencies.

Comment: Yeah its sad. I would never use Groovy for anything if I didn't have to (Jenkins, Maven), at which point adding ANT is just another drop in the ocean.

Comment: Even though I have the `Ant` plugin installed, my `Jenkinsfile` doesn't have the `ant` object loaded or accessible or sth - so this didn't work for me.

Comment: there is not ant in dsl for me...

Answer (score 28):

I use this code to replace port 8080 to ${port.http} directly in certain file:

```
    def file = new File('deploy/tomcat/conf/server.xml')
    def newConfig = file.text.replace('8080', '${port.http}')
    file.text = newConfig
```

The first string reads a line of the file into variable. The second string performs a replace. The third string writes a variable into file.

Comment: This is a very useful answer but I will like to add if you want to replace more than one string, just append ```replace``` method after the previous replace: ```file.text.replace('8080', '${port.http}').replace('str', 'new str')```

Comment: I have doubts the first line reads only one "line of the file into variable"

Answer (score 17):

Answers that use "File" objects are good and quick, but usually cause following error that of course can be avoided but at the cost of loosen security:

> Scripts not permitted to use new java.io.File java.lang.String.
> Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.

This solution avoids all problems presented above:

```
String filenew = readFile('dir/myfile.yml').replaceAll('xxx','YYY')
writeFile file:'dir/myfile2.yml', text: filenew
```

Comment: The only answer that worked for me. You can also one-line it: `writeFile file: 'my-file', text: readFile('my-file').replaceAll('needle', 'replacement)`

Comment: I had issues with character encoding (possibly because of a badly encoded source file). However I used `sed -i 's%searchstring%replacestring%'` to get around it very simple (which is not groovy at all, I know...).

Comment: The OP isn't necessarily asking for a Jenkins solution. FWIW, I came here looking for a Jenkins solution, so this was helpful to me.

Comment: writeFile file:'dir/myfile2.yml', text: filenew. In this file how to pass variable? I am passing like this writeFile file:${var}, text: filenew. It's giving me an error

Answer (score 11):

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16927133/2051952) where patterns are replaced. The same principle can be used to replace strings.

**Sample**

```
def copyAndReplaceText(source, dest, Closure replaceText){
    dest.write(replaceText(source.text))
}

def source = new File('source.txt') //Hello World
def dest = new File('dest.txt') //blank

copyAndReplaceText(source, dest) {
    it.replaceAll('World', 'World!!!!!')
}

assert 'Hello World' == source.text
assert 'Hello World!!!!!' == dest.text
```

Comment: Hi. I Am kinda new to groovy, I've been working with it for two days now. 

if I copy paste the answer you provided will that work on my code?

Comment: @geretd Yes it will but I would not encourage you to just copy the answer. Give it a try in Groovy Console and see how it behaves. Try to understand each line. End of the day it would become a part in your learning curve if you understand it.

Comment: thank you

what I do to learn how  it behave is to copy paste your code in a clean groovy console and try to edit it to work with a text file I already have in a certain directory, to try to understand how it works.

but so far I haven't been able to get it to work. like I said I've never seen this language before and all I have done I have done it by myself by reading and researching on google.

Answer (score 4):

other simple solution would be following closure:

```
def replace = { File source, String toSearch, String replacement ->
        source.write(source.text.replaceAll(toSearch, replacement))
    }
```

Comment: This is nice but it loads the whole file into memory. I do like simplicity, though, and actually it looks more Groovy-like to me. I'm not sure loading it all into memory is an issue, anyway. A smart developer would use a more robust language than Groovy to work on large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

[GStringTemplateEngine](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/GStringTemplateEngine.html) is a nice alternative. It supports GString formatted parameters. For example, if you have `file/my-file.txt` with this content:

```
My contents in the file is like: ${myParameter}
```

Then, you can read and replace the param with:

```
new GStringTemplateEngine().createTemplate(MyClass.class.getClassLoader()
            .getResource("file/my-file.txt").text)
            .make([
                    myParameter: 1234
            ]).toString()
```

Just map the parameters to their values inside the `.make` map.