# how to fix groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:

Tags: groovy

I am trying to use this method without a closure

```
def copyAndReplaceText(source, dest, targetText, replaceText){
    dest.write(source.text.replaceAll(targetText, replaceText))
}

def source = new File('C:/geretd/resumebak.txt') //Hello World
def dest = new File('C:/geretd/resume.txt') //blank

copyAndReplaceText(source, dest){
    it.replaceAll('Visa', 'Passport!!!!')
}
```

but when I run it I get the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ConsoleScript3.copyAndReplaceText() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.File, java.io.File, ConsoleScript3$_run_closure1) values: [C:\geretd\resumebak.txt, C:\geretd\resume.txt, ...]
Possible solutions: copyAndReplaceText(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:78)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From a noob in groovy: I had the same exception, but for different reason. I defined a method later than I wanted to use in the beginning of the code. When I replaced it, it worked.

Comment: Another caveat: If you are calling a static method of an outer class from an inner class without fully qualifying the outer method: `static class Abc {
  private void test() {
   foo();
  }
 }

 private static void foo() {

 }`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because you are passing three arguments to a four arguments method. Also, you are not using the passed closure.

If you want to specify the operations to be made on top of the `source` contents, then use a closure. It would be something like this:

```
def copyAndReplaceText(source, dest, closure){
    dest.write(closure( source.text ))
}

// And you can keep your usage as:
copyAndReplaceText(source, dest){
    it.replaceAll('Visa', 'Passport!!!!')
}
```

If you will always swap strings, pass both, as your method signature already states:

```
def copyAndReplaceText(source, dest, targetText, replaceText){
    dest.write(source.text.replaceAll(targetText, replaceText))
}

copyAndReplaceText(source, dest, 'Visa', 'Passport!!!!')
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this my first time with groovy, and I need help, quick question if I use the code below I will be passing 4 parameter right? 

`def copyAndReplaceText(source, dest, targetText, replaceText){
    dest.write(source.text.replaceAll(targetText, replaceText))
}

def source = new File('C:/geretd/resumebak.txt') //Hello World
def dest = new File('C:/geretd/resume.txt') //blank


copyAndReplaceText(source, dest, 'Visa', 'Passport!!!!')`

Comment: Yes. `copyAndReplaceText()` is the method name, and you are passing four arguments: 1st `source`, 2nd `dest`, 3rd `'Visa'` and 4th `'Passport!!!!'`

Comment: well honestly I never heard of groovy before until Friday, I have had to research on my own, now I am stuck at this requirement.

 search and replace to temporary file named xxxx~, old text with new text

don't know how to do it

Comment: But yeah I figured out groovy is very nice, it is not as rigid as java, even though it has it's base on it.

Comment: @geretd [Tim's approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17403055/2051952) to your earlier question in addition to the one you are using now will be useful once you are comfortable with the semantics and syntax of Groovy.

Comment: I got this error in a Jenkins - Pileline environment. I quickly tell the solution, to others from searching endlessly.

I defined a groovy library with, the pipeline was calling it:
def call(String xxx, String yyy) { 
}
The problem was I had a env.YYY defined in my pipeline calling the groovy library and it seems to collide with the parameter name from the call method, so I renamed my parameter to yyyy.

Answer (score 19):

To help other bug-hunters. I had this error because the function didn't exist.

I had a spelling error.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. My method names were not the same case. Oops!

Answer (score 10):

In my case it was simply that I had a variable named the same as a function.

Example:

```
def cleanCache = functionReturningABoolean()

if( cleanCache ){
    echo "Clean cache option is true, do not uninstall previous features / urls"
    uninstallCmd = ""
    
    // and we call the cleanCache method
    cleanCache(userId, serverName)
}
...
```

and later in my code I have the function:

```
def cleanCache(user, server){

 //some operations to the server

}
```

Apparently the Groovy language does not support this (but other languages like Java does).
I just renamed my function to `executeCleanCache` and it works perfectly (or you can also rename your variable whatever option you prefer).

Answer (score 2):

You can also get this error if the objects you're passing to the method are out of order. In other words say your method takes, in order, a string, an integer, and a date. If you pass a date, then a string, then an integer you will get the same error message.

Comment: You can get this error any time your argument list is not correct for the method signature...

Answer (score 2):

This may also be because you might have given classname with all letters in lowercase something which groovy (know of version 2.5.0) does not support.

class name - User is accepted but user is not.

Answer (score 1):

Also obtained by calling an instance method from a static method.
Solution. Add missing static keyword to the instance method

Answer (score 1):

Another one - If you try to call a super method / constructor that is marked private.
If you're extending a class make sure everything your child class touches is marked as protected or public.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem is I commented firebase dependency in `build.gradle` file but still using this in debug build type:

```
firebaseCrashlytics {
   mappingFileUploadEnabled true
}
```

Just make it commented to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

This was one of the major issues for the ionic/android app

Please follow the below steps.

1. Remove/Delete node-module from root folder
2. npm uninstall cordova-android
3. npm install cordova-android@10.1.1
4. Now remove android platform using: ionic cordova rm platform android
5. Now add platform : ionic cordova platform add android
6. Build Android Project : ionic cordova build android

Problem will be resolved