# What does MissingMethodException mean?

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, manifest, missingmethodexception

I picked it up from a [presentation on Continuous Delivery](https://www.infoq.com/fr/presentations/codeurs-en-seine-jean-philippe-briend-jenkins)
It is supposed to create, read and update a manifest.
I can run it only once.

```
def writePropertiesFile( props, file ) {
    writeFile file: file, text: writeProperties(props)
}
@NonCPS def writeProperties( props ){
    def sw = new StringWriter()
    props.store( sw, null )
    return sw.toString()
}
node() {
    stage( 'Reading manifest' ) {
        try{
            copyArtifacts filter: 'manifest', 
                fingerprintArtifacts: true, 
                projectName: env.JOB_NAME, 
                selector: lastSuccessful()
            versions = readProperties( file: 'manifest' )
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            echo e.toString()
            versions = new Properties()
        }
    }
    stage( 'Merging manifest' ) {
        versions.put( 'dev', '1.2.3' )
    }
    stage( "Writing manifest" ) {
        writePropertiesFile( versions, 'manifest' )
        archive 'manifest'
    }
}
```

The first time it works correctly.

It creates a manifest like this

> ```
> #Wed Mar 21 16:30:34 CET 2018
> dev=1.2.3
> ```

The second time, when I want to update the manifest I get this error :
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.HashMap.store() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.StringWriter, null) values: [, null]

I am absolutely no Java coder and I've seen some questions about this MissingMethodException that I haven't understood. For example [how to fix groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411209/how-to-fix-groovy-lang-missingmethodexception-no-signature-of-method)

Comment: *"I am absolutely no Java coder"* Groovy isn't Java, it just runs on the JVM.

Comment: "It isn't Java", I agree. But it is a lot more Java-like than the script languages I'm used to. But about this MissingMethodException?