# Jmeter- Iterate and change file values

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jmeter, I have a test plan where I have updated request thread group.

Before processing the request, in this thread group, I want to copy the input file of this updated requests and put it into another file. In newly copied file, I want to change the value of a particular column (for example: "C1") and save.

Can we do this by adding JSR223 pre-processor? if that is the case, how can we write the script to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using any suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), the example code which:

1. Reads `source.txt` file
2. Replaces `bar` with `Groovy written this line`
3. Saves the result into `destination.txt`

Would look something like:

```
new File('source.txt').readLines().each { line ->
    new File('destination.txt') << line.replaceAll('bar', 'Groovy written this line')  + System.getProperty('line.separator')
}
```

You can also see answers to [how to replace a string/word in a text file in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395787/how-to-replace-a-string-word-in-a-text-file-in-groovy) question for other approaches.

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Replace line in file]

Check out [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) article for several useful Groovy code snippets you can use as a basis.

Comment: I used this below code and it worked for me
resFileFind1 = new File("C:/find.csv");
  reqFileUpdateChange = new File("C:/update.csv");
  fileData = FileUtils.readFileToString(resFileFind1);
  fileData = fileData.replaceAll("u@com.com", "B@com.com");
  FileUtils.writeStringToFile(reqFileUpdateChange, fileData);