# Use jenkins or groovy script to change a text in a file

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I have a file with 3 lines of text. where I need to change a text from "true" to "false". I have tried using python code to change text of a file. That didn't help. I am stuck as to how I can do this using Jenkins script.
I have used this past solution. However, I am not able to make it work
[how to replace a string/word in a text file in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395787/how-to-replace-a-string-word-in-a-text-file-in-groovy)

Comment: Hello Alan, what error are you getting; if you can your piece of code and sample file; that will help

Comment: Hi Pankaj, thank you for the feedback.                            java.io.FileNotFoundException.                                                                                 It's a Python file which is not being read by groovy.                                                    def file = new File('......./abc.py')
def newConfig = file.text.replace('False', 'True')
file.text = newConfig